Which characters seen in Amazon's Fallout TV series originate in the video game franchise from which it is spun off?
Which characters that are seen on screen — and which are portrayed by actors, and specifically identified, rather than merely being mentioned or alluded to — originate from the video game franchise from which the series was spun off, and where in the franchise were they drawn from?
For example, Robert House, founder of Robco, seen in Series 1 episode 8 and portrayed by Rafi Silver, was an original character created for Obsidian Entertainment's Fallout: New Vegas, published by Bethesda in 2010.

This sort of covers it:
Mr House:


Appearances
Robert House appears in Fallout: New Vegas and the Fallout TV series. He is mentioned in Fallout 4 and Fallout 76.


House appears smoking a cigarette at a meeting with many major CEOs in the Fallout TV Series, with a nameplate clearly labeled "RobCo" in front of him.


Why is Mr. House in Fallout?
He's in the show–understandably–because he's one of the major players in the pre-war world. Vault-Tec wanted to serve the interests of anyone with power and money, determining they were the best ones to rebuild society. And Mr. House, a tech genius and wealthy businessman, naturally got a seat at the table to decide America's future.

https://www.menshealth.com/entertainment/a60481830/fallout-season-1-finale-mr-house-cameo/
https://www.menshealth.com/entertainment/a60444917/fallout-tv-show-timeline-location/
https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Robert_House
Frederick Sinclair, a lesser cameo:

Frederick Sinclair appears in the Fallout: New Vegas add-on Dead Money as a skeleton and is mentioned in the add-on Old World Blues. He also appears in a pre-War scene in the Fallout TV series episode "The Beginning."

https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Frederick_Sinclair
(As noted in the link supplied, there are inconsistencies with how Sinclair is portrayed in the tv show)
As to why other characters do not feature or appear in the tv show:

The show takes place in Los Angeles, a location never explored before in the game
While the show is still within the general timeframe of the games, the location is separate enough that characters from the games likely wouldn't show up on the show. Fallout 3 takes place 200 years after the nuclear fallout as well, but is set on the complete other side of the country, where there's likely little to no connection. Fallout 4 is 10 years after its predecessor, but also takes place in New England. And Fallout: New Vegas is set a decade before the show, although it does take place in California and Nevada.


(As an example of alluded to in the games but not seen and only portrayed in the tv show: Leon Von Felden of West-Tek, mentioned in Fallout and in Fallout 3, but is only seen in the tv show)
